# ACCESS DENIED ROOT@LOCALHOST USING PASSWORD YES

Tags: phpmyadmin

I know very little about programming, which means that whatever I learned, I learned it from youtube. So in order to explain my problem I am writing everything, so when I get a reply I can understand it.

First I tried to download Apache, MySQL and phpMyAdmin but did not succeed.

After that I downloaded XAMPP 1.7.7

In XAMPP 1.7.7 I gave this information for my security.

**MYSQL SECTION: "ROOT" PASSWORD (This line was already there as a heading)** 
**MYSQL super user : root (it was already there so i can't change it)**
password : bluebus
PhpMyAdmin authentification: http or cokie (I selected cokie)
Safe plain password in text file? ((File: C:\xampp\security\security\mysqlrootpasswd.txt): there was a check box I did not click.

**XAMPP DIRECTORY PROTECTION (.htaccess) (this line was already there as a heading)**

User: bus
Password : bluebuss
Safe plain password in text file? ((File: C:\xampp\security\security\mysqlrootpasswd.txt): there was a check box I did not click.

*AFTER THAT I WENT TO PHPMYADMIN*
user : root
password: redbus

I created a database, DATABASE NAME: CAR
I added a new user for this database, NEW USER NAME: CAR, and password I gave again **"redbus"**, and I created a table

Then I created a new file in notepad++, the code is

```
<?php

define ('DB_NAME', 'car');
define ('DB_USER', 'car');
define ('DB_PASWORD', 'redbus');
define ('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

$link= mysql_connect (DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD);

if (!$link) {
die ('could not connect:' . mysql_error () );
}

$db_selected=mysql_selected_db (DB_NAME, $link);

if (!$db_selected) {
die ('cant user' . ':' . mysql_error ());
}

$value = $_post ['input1'];

$sql= "INSERT INTO demo (input1) VALUES ('$value')";

if (!mysql_query ($sql)) {
die ('error:' . mysql_error () );
}

mysql_close ();
?>
```

When i tried to run it, it gave me this error, and I don't understand why:

`**Notice:** *Use of undefined constant DB_PASSWORD - assumed 'DB_PASSWORD' in C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpProject1\index.php on line 8*`

`**[Warning:** *mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Access denied for user 'car'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpProject1\index.php on line 8*`

`Could not connect: Access denied for user 'malakiarif'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

Please help me guys, I tried to find out the answer by googling and wasted my whole week but could not find an answer.

thanks

Answer (score 2):

You misspelled "DB_PASSWORD" as "DB_PASWORD" on line 4.

Comment: thanks my freind i corrected it error one its finish but this one is still remaining                 Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Access denied for user 'arif'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpProject1\index.php on line 8
could not connect:Access denied for user 'arif'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: thanks my freind i corrected it error one its finish but this one is still remaining Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Access denied for user 'arif'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpProject1\index.php on line 8 could not connect:Access denied for user 'arif'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: i think i was doing some stupid mistake so this time i added a new user name: member, password: redblue and changed the coding accordingly on line 4 and and five now its look like ......              define ('DB_USER', 'member');                                       but after running it is giving me the error **Fatal Error:** Call to undefined function mysql_selected_db() in C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpProject1\index.php on line 14 
define ('DB_PASSWORD', 'redblue');....... line 14 is $db_selected=mysql_selected_db (DB_NAME, $link);...                thanks for help